# Docker compose init?

Tags: docker

I am confused about how to run `docker-compose.yml` based applications on startup.

I'm running:

- https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole/blob/master/docker-compose.yml
- https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/smokeping

In two tmux sessions right now, via `docker-compose up`. But that doesn't help me when the machine reboots.

Answer (score 3):

First you should enable your docker service to start on every boot by using `sudo systemctl enable /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`.

Then you should start your docker-compose containers with `docker-compose up -d`.

> ```
> -d, --detach               Detached mode: Run containers in the background,
>                            print new container names. Incompatible with
>                            --abort-on-container-exit.
> ```
>
> (from: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/)

As far as I know containers running in the detached mode should also restart on a reboot.

If you still want to the the logs or if your containers are running and so on you should get familiar with the different compose CLI commands. See [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/)